# Simple Tweet from the app Android

Tags: android, twitter, authentication, tweets

How do I setup simple a Tweet from an app. Login must be through the twitter website. 
The user even have to  fill in any text. I just need to tweet. Please provide and example.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help you:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(
  android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
  "I'm a string that you want to tweet);
startActivity(
  Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_via)));
```

This is actually generic sharing code. It will get all the application that can handle a Send Action (like facebook, twitter, e-mail, etc.) and let the user choose what application to use. This is the type of functionality you commonly see in a "share" button on an android app.

Comment: Unfortunately I really need only Tweeter, open the web site to login and return to app to send the tweet. Got 4 buttons, email, sms, facebook and tweeter.

Comment: Why not just combine all of those into one share button, and then let the user choose which one they want to use as a share. My method above will allow them to select from all of the stuff you've outlined.

Comment: Believe me that I will prefer your method, but this is not my decision.